# How to filter query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table like this :

```
ID   USER1    USER2     USER3
1      D        Y         N
2      C        B         M
3      E        R         U
4      F        Y         A
5      G        B         K
```

How to filter and show 1 value Y & 1 value B instead 2 value Y and 2 value B in USER2
CODE:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT USER2 FROM TABLE");
<p><select name="select" id="select">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo '<option value='.$row["USER2"].'>'.$row["USER2"].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
      </select></p>
```

In Select control it show 2 value B and 2 value Y. I want it show 1 value Y and 1 value B (Unique value)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: @Ivan user `group by USER2' or `distinct USER2` in selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show distinct values, you need to say so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER2 FROM TABLE
```

But your table design is likely to cause trouble down the road, if you need to handle more than three users…

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT USER2 FROM TABLE");
```

Comment: query first working like charm
query second not working. Nothing show :)

Comment: @Ivan yes, sorry for misleading you. I used the `ORDER BY` whereas no aggregate function is used, that is why the second query was false.

Answer (score 0):

you should use distinct in your sql query.
you can simply do some thing like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER2 FROM TABLE where USER2 = Y or USER2 = B
```

here is a good starting point in sql DISTINCT keyword :
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: This query selects Y, R, B. While OP needs Y and B

Comment: you can simply do some thing like this :
SELECT DISTINCT USER2 FROM TABLE where USER2 = Y or USER2 = B